# Why are there two blog post links on Stack Overflow currently?

Tags: bug, user-interface, blog

Currently on Stack Overflow, but not other sites, there are *two* links to the blog post about SO in Russian.

[image: Blog posts galore!]

Why?
I mean, I'm all for welcoming our future Russian overlords, but two in a row seems to be a bit much.

Comment: *"Someone pulled the gun faster than you :)"*